# How can i explain, what is Spark RDD exactly, in good and crisp terms

Tags: apache-spark

I am giving training on Spark to my junior and got this question in my mind.
I know the conceptual knowledge of RDD and how great concept it is and how it made distributed programming much faster.

But, not satisfied with the explanation i have given to him about RDD. Want to get best description for it and posting this question.

Comment: This might help. It includes the link to of the paper on RDD by UC Berkley goo.gl/wQwG7m

Comment: For me the best way to understand RDDs was reading rdd class. Its pretty long but code is quite easy (at least conceputally) if you have working understanding of spark.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple illustration of RDD interface taken from :[Spark Summit 2015](https://spark-summit.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/SparkSummitEast2015-AdvDevOps-StudentSlides.pdf)

**RDD Interface** contains

- Set of partitions (“splits”)
- List of dependencies on parent RDDs
- Function to compute a partition given parents
- Optional preferred locations
- Optional partitioning info for k/v RDDs (Partitioner)

Now taking example of **HadoopRDD**:

- Partitions = one per HDFS block
- Dependencies = none
- Compute (partition) = read corresponding block
- preferredLocations (part) = HDFS block location
- Partitioner = none

Taking example of **FilteredRDD**

- Partitions = same as parent RDD
- Dependencies = “one-to-one” on parent
- Compute (partition) = compute parent and filter it
- preferredLocations (part) = none (ask parent)
- Partitioner = none

So basically RDD is nothing but a data structure to store lineage and other information for recreating it in case of failures, which is the main idea behind Matei Zaharia's paper.